# Correct method to pass Zap Absence of Anti-CSRF Tokens test for newsletter signup form

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, owasp, zap

I have a public facing form that, I believe, does not need CSRF protection. It is just a newsletter signup form. But when we run Zap Pen Test on it we get the following error:

```
No Anti-CSRF tokens were found in a HTML submission form.

Evidence:
<form data-cookie-name="newsletter" data-marketo-id="1031" id="newsletterForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submit(newsletterForm)" ng-controller="NewsletterSignupController" name="newsletterForm">
```

This newsletter uses Angular as a controller and we are doing a POST in the controller to send the email to the server.

Questions:

1. Do I really need to implement CSRF tokens on a public facing Form? If not, how do I get the Pen Test to pass without this error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a "best practices" way to implement anti-csrf protection in Angular. Maybe dig on that front a little more, as you probably want to protect all your user inputs. If I recall, there's a way to configure this in respective JS frameworks. Otherwise as the other answer below, maybe there's a way to ignore it or set your test to mock an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Well you can mark it false positive (in the GUI or via the API).
- You can setup an [Alert Filter](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/alert-filters/) to set it False Posituve.
- You can set a [rule configuration](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/options/ruleconfig/) to ignore the form in question.

Whether you need to prevent CSRF on the form is a business owner question. Are there processing concerns? Are there concerns around complaints or reputational damage?

Comment: No processing concerns, complaints, or reputational damage. Just the first pen test our startup is going through for a client and we are trying to meet the requirements in a quick and correct manner. These forms don't actually need CSRF and I wanted to see if there is an accepted method to get around these results without actually implementing CSRF. And your answer helped a lot. Thanks!